The DELETE method is not supported for route logout. Supported methods: POST
I want to use the CRUD in my web project, I imported the starter kit breeze to have a CRUD (after the project has been created / bit too late)
Unfortunately I can't access to the method from the controller I always get redirected to the log out method through another controller AuthenticatedSessionController which call an aother destroy method to logout.
In this case I would my view to call the Profile controller and not the Authenticated Controller and apply the CRUD method
AuthenticatedSessionController  :
 public function logout(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {

        Auth::guard('web')->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect('/');
    }

ProfileController : (the one should destroy, edit, etc) :
public function edit(Request $request): View
    {
        return view('profile.edit', [
            'user' => $request->user(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the user's profile information.
     */
    public function update(ProfileUpdateRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $request->user()->fill($request->validated());

        if ($request->user()->isDirty('email')) {
            $request->user()->email_verified_at = null;
        }

        $request->user()->save();

        return Redirect::route('profile.edit')->with('status', 'profile-updated');
    }


    public function destroy(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {

        $request->validateWithBag('userDeletion', [
            'password' => ['required', 'current_password'],
        ]);

        $user = $request->user();

        Auth::logout();

        $user->delete();

        $request->session()->invalidate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return Redirect::route('/')
            ->with('success', __('messages.user_deleted_successfully'));
    }


My route web.php
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {

    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
//    dd('124');
//    Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');


});
require __DIR__.'/auth.php';

My route auth.php
  Route::post('logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'logout'])
                ->name('logout');

    Route::delete('/profile', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroyUser'])->name('profile.destroy');

and my view :
 <form action="{{ route('profile.destroy', auth()->user()->name) }}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        @method('delete')
                        <button type="submit" class="text-white bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-red-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2.5 text-center mr-2 dark:focus:ring-red-900">Delete</button>
                    </form>


remove "   @method('delete')"

It is causing your logout to use DELETE request instead of POST request

I must be missing something. All I see in the code is a form with profile.destory as target (which is set as DELETE in your routes so I don't see why @method('delete') would be a problem in that form?) I also see you actually referencing that delete-route anywhere else?

Yes indeed I already added the post method to the logout and the delete method to delete but it's either a logout or the mthod is not supported.. It appears that my request in the route was not connected to the controller and couldn't call it properly
